# How to create a chunked list of lists with almost-equal lengths?

Tags: python, function, python-3.8

I need to split a number into 3 parts. The following function ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117390/9997212)) does that correctly:

```py
def parts(num: int, div: int) -> list[int]:
    """Split a number into equal parts."""
    return [num // div + (1 if x < num % div else 0) for x in range(div)]
```

So

```py
assert parts(8, 3) == [3, 3, 2]
assert parts(9, 3) == [3, 3, 3]
assert parts(10, 3) == [4, 3, 3]
```

From that list, I need a list of lists containing a range from 0 to `num + 3`, such that every sublist

- at an even index has a length of 1
- at an odd index has a length of `n`, where `n` is fetched from `parts`

```py
assert expected(8, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10]]
assert expected(9, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
assert expected(10, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

This is what I've tried:

```py
def actual(num: int, div: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    matrix: list[list[int]] = []
    for i, length in enumerate(parts(num, div)):
        base = i * (length + 1)
        matrix.append([base])
        matrix.append([base + j + 1 for j in range(length)])

    return matrix
```

However, it only works when `num` is divisible by `div`. How can I fix it?

These are the outputs for my function:

```py
assert actual(8, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [6], [7, 8]]
assert actual(9, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
assert actual(10, 3) == [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: Why does the `div` parameter exist when it's always 3?

Comment: @KellyBundy Because it's easier to adapt the code if this requirement change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each sub list contains incrementing numbers. This is what `itertools.count` can give you.

I've adapted your function to use it like this:

```py
from itertools import count

def actual(num: int, div: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    matrix: list[list[int]] = []
    base = count(0)
    for length in parts(num, div):
        matrix.append([next(base)])
        matrix.append([next(base) for _ in range(length)])

    return matrix
```

Comment: Your answer involved no arithmetic and also removed `i` and `j`. I was looking for something like that!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `base = i * (length + 1)`, start out with `base = 0` (before the loop), and just increment `base` by however many elements you added in that iteration.

```
def actual(num: int, div: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    base = 0
    matrix: list[list[int]] = []
    for i, length in enumerate(parts(num, div)):
        matrix.append([base])
        matrix.append([base + j + 1 for j in range(length)])
        base += 1+ length
    return matrix
```

Comment: Your answer worked very well for me, thank you so much! I forgot to keep track of `base` between each iteration. However, I really liked the functional approach of the other answer.

Comment: I was purposely trying to show you the bug in your code, rather than rewriting the algorithm from scratch.  I also like the other solution.